# Where does this NULL tuple comes from

Tags: sql

I realy don´t get it, why and where sometimes a null tuple comes from. I´d compared the input-data and there is nothing, from where i could tell "ok this is different, that´s the problem".
So sometimes it get attached and sometimes not.

```
select
XP1.SOME_ID,
coalesce(AA1.NumberPP,KK1.NumberPP) as NumberPP,
coalesce(AA1.TNumB,KK1.TNumB) as TNumB,
coalesce(AA1.XY_ID,KK1.XY_ID) as TNumB,
coalesce(AA1.SAM,KK1.SAM) as SAM,
......
,
FROM TaB1 t1
INNER JOIN TaYY1 XP1 on t1.ID = XP1.ID
LEFT JOIN TaB1 AA1 on
(
   t1.M_ID is null
   and AA1.M_ID is null
   and AA1.XY_ID is not null
   and t1.XY_ID is not null
   and t1.XY_ID = AA1.XY_ID
   AND t1.NumberPP = AA1.NumberPP
   AND t1.TNumB = AA1.TNumB 
)
left join TaB1 KK1 on
(
   t1.M_ID is not null
   and t1.XY_ID is null
   and KK1.M_ID is not null
   and KK1.XY_ID is null
   and t1.M_ID = KK1.M_ID
)
```

Output:

```
SOME_ID NumberPP    TNumB   XY_ID    SAM      xy     yx       xx
1      <null>       <null>    32     s.th    xyz     123    <null>
1      <null>       <null>  <null>  <null>  <null>  <null>  <null>
1         1           2       32     s.th    xyz      123     55
```

(T1.M_ID and AA1.XY_ID) can be null and the other keys not null in TaB1 t1 and the other way in TaB1 KK1.

Later a better one, but input is like that:

```
   M_ID     XY_ID     OTHERID(not in code)     SAM    Car      Color
  213424    null      null                      Kts    Tesla     Red
   null     1236       14                       PRS    BMW       Black
```

And in some cases the output is like:

```
SOME_ID  SAM     Car    Color
1         Kts   Tesla    Red
1         null   null    null
1         PRS    BMW     BLACK
```

Sry for the edits, i hope the small input table is now ok..later a better one.

Comment: Can you show the table data also?

Comment: If you expect at least one of those left joins to succeed, it's not obvious why (i.e. the join conditions aren't obviously "covering" for all possible input value). But if you need that, you can craft a `WHERE` clause that ensures that one of those `LEFT JOIN`s has succeeded. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: The most obvious cause for neither join to succeed would be if you have a row in `Tab1` where `m_id` and `xy_id` are either both `null` or both non-`null`.

Comment: The joins work, but the extra row with the null´s is strange. I hope its now better understandable with the small input table.

Comment: The results say otherwise - that output is exactly what you'll see if neither left join is successful for any particular row produced by joining `Tab1` and `TaYY1`. Either that or one of the joins is successful but the row joined to contains `null`s in all selected columns, but I'd have hoped that wouldn't surprise you and so I assume that possibility is already eliminated.

Comment: Its not the case... and there is a small example where the input data contains 2 rows, just like the input sample and the output generates that third null null null row... i rly dont get it, the row dont belong to the output table, just the 2 rows with the data, in this case. I have selected everything from the 2 tables, to check if perhaps something has a value in the output, but nothing...every column from that row containt "null"

Answer (score 0):

You tables `TAB1` is joined twice with a `LEFT JOIN`, so it means that if a matching row is not found in the `TAB1` then it will display NULL for all the columns of `TAB1`. That is how the `LEFT JOIN` works.

Also, you are using coalesce, so sometimes the data is coming from AA1 and sometimes it is coming from KK1. If you change your select statement to the following then it might become easier for you to understand.

```
select
XP1.SOME_ID,
AA1.NumberPP,
KK1.NumberPP,
AA1.TNumB,
KK1.TNumB,
AA1.XY_ID,
KK1.XY_ID,
AA1.SAM,
KK1.SAM,
......
```

Comment: But in this case the input table has 2 tuples, so there are matches?! Sorry i don´t get it, relative new to sql... and i dont know how else to get the two Tables together... can i exclude something?!

Comment: It would help if you can post a sample table structure and tell us what exactly are you trying to do.

Comment: @NoOne I added some more info to my answer please check if you are able to understand it.

Comment: Because sometimes the  t1.M_ID IS NULL and sometimes not, like the other key pair. Depends on that i have to get the data. I can add a sample table later. I know what you mean, perhaps my question isnt understandle. Gonna add a small example table, later a better one.